# How to key "Ctrl + Shift + i" in selenium webdriver python Error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to press ctrl + shift + i to open inspector mode but it doesn't work

```
import selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains as action_chains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

pulsar = action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
pulsar.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys("i").perform()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open Inspect Elements by passing desired command line arguments
These arguments will open inspect elements when the browser launches

For [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open)

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

For [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)

```
firefox_options = webdriver.firefox.options.Options()
firefox_options.add_argument("-devtools")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)
```